# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version') at ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am getting error updating vue version to 3 using bootstrap-vue.

```
warn  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js                                                                                                   22:59:50
```

```
export 'default' (reexported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (pos
```

As of their documentation i am using @vue-compat.

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.18",
        "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
        "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
        "@coreui/vue": "^2.1.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^3.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.27",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
        "bootstrap-vue": "npm:@ankurk91/bootstrap-vue@^3.0.2", 
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "core-js": "^3.25.3",
        "css-vars-ponyfill": "^2.4.8",
        "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "roboto-npm-webfont": "^1.0.1",
        "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
        "vue": "^3.1.0",
        "@vue/compat": "^3.2.41",
        "vue-cal": "^2.24.8",
        "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.1",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.27.2",
        "vue-loader": "^17.1.0",
        "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
        "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.0",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5"
    }
}
```

I tried to change version of bootstrap-vue as well as @vue-compat but it did't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you for reponse. I found problem was my webpack configuration. I forgot to add this section

```html
    alias: {
      vue: '@vue/compat'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the proper package installed

`"bootstrap-vue": "npm:@ankurk91/bootstrap-vue@^3.0.2"`

should be replaced with

`"bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1"`

Comment: Thank you for your response but it was not really the case.